# How do I prove that a determinant function exists and is multilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I understand why it has to be multilinear, but am unable to show it mathematically. I think induction would be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to get started.

Edit:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you defining the determinant? [I ask because it can be defined in a way that makes it obvious that it is multilinear.]

Comment: I'm not sure what this form is called, but I use the $f(A_1,A_2,....,A_n)=det(A_1,....A_n) f(e_1,......,e_n)$

Comment: You still haven't said how you are defining det.

Comment: As per the definition you've shown in the images, proving it is multilinear is not a problem. It is part of the definition! If it isn't multilinear, then it isn't a determinant function. Proving it exists is somewhat harder, but one can just resort to the classical formula.

Comment: That definition of alternating is poorly stated. "for some" usually means "there exists", but what is needed here is "for all".